# Get the max count of an array inside array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array inside the array and I want to get the Highest count of that Array,

```
List<int> badnumber = new List<int>() { 5,4,2, 15 };
int lower = 1;
int upper = 10;

int count = 0;

List<int> goodnumber = new List<int>();
List<List<int>> myList = new List<List<int>>();

for (int i = lower; i <= upper; i++)
{
    if (!badnumber.Contains(i))
    {
        if (!goodnumber.Contains(i))
            goodnumber.Add(i);
    }
    else
    {
        myList.Add(goodnumber);
        goodnumber = new List<int>();
    }

    if (i == upper) {
        myList.Add(goodnumber);
    }
}
```

in `myList` values are like this

```
Array 1 : { 1 }
Array 2 : { 3 }
Array 3 : { 0 }
Array 4 : { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }
```

I want to get the count of the highest sequence which is Array 4. and return the count of it which is 5.

how would I get that?

Comment: First off:: arrays are not lists. Leaving that asside, what did you try? You surely know how to get the length of a list, don´t you? Just iterare all lists and get that one with the greatest count. It´s the exact same task as chosing the greatest number in a collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use following sample

```
    var maxCount = myList.Max(l => l.Count);
```

Comment: is there a way sir to optimize my code above? because the running time for the code above is exceeding in 3 secs. how can I make it 2 or below?

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
            List<List<int>> myList = new List<List<int>>() {
                new List<int> { 1},
                new List<int> { 3},
                new List<int> { 0},
                new List<int> { 6,7,8,9,10}
            };

            int results = myList.Max(x => x.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically your task boils down to the following:

> How to get the greatest number in a list

In order to achieve that, you have to iterate that (outer) list, get every elements member you want to compare - in your case the `Count` - and check if it is greater the current `Max`:

```
int max = 0;
foreach(var l in myList)
{
    if(l.Count > max)
        max = l.Count;
}
```

or even simpler using linq, see jdweng.

Comment: Or `foreach(...) max = Math.Max(max, l.Count);`

Answer (score 0):

Try below lambda to get index position with count:

```
int index = 0;
var result = myList.Select(x => new { indexPos = ++index, x.Count }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).First();
```

Comment: `MaxBy` from MoreLINQ may be preferable to `OrderByDescending` and `First`.

Comment: I agree with you. I could able to get the same result using MoreLINQ library.
Below is sample query which gives the same result:

_var result2 = myList.Select(x => new { indexPos = ++index, x.Count }).MaxBy(x => x.Count);_