# Is there a way to make the Loop Code make it faster?

Tags: c#

[For Loop Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63499987/get-the-max-count-of-an-array-inside-array/63500346#63500346)

```
 int counts = 0;
            List<int> count = new List<int>();
            List<int> goodnumber = new List<int>();
            for (int i = lower; i <= upper; i++)
            {
                if (!badNumbers.Contains(i)) {
                        goodnumber.Add(i);
                } else {
                    count.Add(goodnumber.Count);
                    goodnumber = new List<int>();
                } 
                if (i == upper) {
                    count.Add(goodnumber.Count);
                    counts = count.Max();
                }
            }
            return counts;
```

is there a way to optimize my code above? because the running time for the code above is exceeding in 3 secs. how can I make it 2 or below?

Comment: Can you include the code in this post instead of link?

Comment: I added the code sir.

Comment: @G10 I added the code sir

Comment: Well, I think you don't know what you are doing... You should read your code a few times and take a paper an a pen and draw the algorithm.

Comment: Make `badNumbers` a `HashSet<int>`

Comment: Why not use any of those solutions you were already given? That code is quite hard to understand.

Comment: Given your comment below: *"Still exceeding on the time limit sir"*, I'm guessing this is an online programming test or something, and they want you to reduce your asymptotic complexity.  Do you have a description of what you are trying to do (your code is hard to follow)? The problem is that you are calling `badNumbers.Contains(i)` within a loop.  I'm pretty sure that `.Contains` is **O(N)**, so you are getting **O(N^2)** behavior.  They (whoever they are) want you to reduce that

Comment: What's the value of upper and lower you have? What's this code is written for?

Comment: OP could easily get a job as an obfuscator. He is trying to find the longest sequence of numbers between numbers from "badNumbers" bound by "lower" and "upper".

Comment: Are you still struggling with this question? I note that you haven't accepted any of the answers, nor have you provided any new feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few improvements you can make.

1. `badNumbers` should probably be a `HashSet<int>` which will provide you close to O(1) lookup.
2. You don't actually care about storing the "good numbers" (you don't use that data), so it would be more efficient to just store how many good numbers you encounter.
3. Now you just want the max streak size (i.e. max number of consecutive good numbers) you encounter, and you can use `Math.Max` to compare the last "good" count with the current "good" count and choose the largest.

The code looks like this:

```
HashSet<int> badNumbers = new HashSet<int>() { 5, 4, 2, 15 };
int counts = 0;
int goodNumberCount = 0;
for (int i = lower; i <= upper; i++)
{
    if (!badNumbers.Contains(i)) {
        ++goodNumberCount;
    } else {
        counts = Math.Max(counts, goodNumberCount);
        goodNumberCount = 0;
    }
}
counts = Math.Max(counts, goodNumberCount); 
return counts;
```

Comment: From his other question, the bad numbers are `{ 5, 4, 2, 15 }`. And you missed a `;`. ;) *(now updated)*

Comment: @Andrew You're quite right, I did :D Thank you! And thank you for the numbers OP is dealing with.

Comment: @John, Hi Sir. Is there a way to limit the running time to 3 seconds if the `upper` value is 100000000?

Comment: @LevesqueXylia Run it on a faster machine. How are you determining how long it takes?

Comment: @John, there are 2 test cases that has no output because the time limit is 3 seconds only.

Comment: I've tested `lower = 0; upper = 100000000;` using BenchmarkDotNet on my i7 machine, and it took an average of 566.8 milliseconds.

Comment: @John, I mean 1 trillion sir. sorry 1 zero is missing. It took 8 seconds.

Comment: @LevesqueXylia I'm not sure how you could make that faster with the code you're using. Parallel would be difficult since you're effectively looking for runs of good numbers. The best thing you could do is determine the maximum "bad number" prior to starting, and then calculate `counts` from that if you pass it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Call `List.Clear()` instead of creating new List inside the loop
2. Call `count.Max()` outside the loop
3. Remove the last if and add this line after the loop `count.Add(goodnumber.Count)`

   ```
       int counts = 0;
       List<int> count = new List<int>();
       List<int> goodnumber = new List<int>();
       for (int i = lower; i <= upper; i++)
       {
           if (!badNumbers.Contains(i)) {
                   goodnumber.Add(i);
           } else {
               count.Add(goodnumber.Count);
               goodnumber.Clear();
           } 

       }

       count.Add(goodnumber.Count);
       counts = count.Max();
       return counts;
   ```

BTW, I don't know what are you trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: Still exceeding on the time limit sir.

Comment: Are you timing release build?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to "optimize" your code is to rewrite it. You need to think differently. The problem you have has various different solutions and you are complicating it too much.

You don't need to process the input in one long cycle only. You can pre-process the list somehow, in a way, that would help you. For example sort it.

Another thing that could help you is to have a variable (or variables) in which you are storing some intermediate result. For example running max, min, sum, or previous value of something

Think about how you could solve the problem mathematically. Isn't it just the difference of numbers you are trying to find?

You could sort the list, calculate the difference between each element, bound it by your lower and upper borders. You can either update the running maximum difference during the loop or find the maximum difference from the list of differences.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general solution:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lower = 1;
            var upper = 10;
            var elementCount = upper - lower + 1;
            var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, elementCount);
            var badNumbers = new HashSet<int> { 5, 4, 2, 15 };
            var maxCount = CalculateCounts(numbers, badNumbers).Max();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<int> CalculateCounts<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, ISet<T> splitOn)
        {
            var count = 0;

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if (!splitOn.Contains(item)) count++;
                else
                {
                    yield return count;
                    count = 0;
                }
            }

            yield return count;
        }
    }
}
```